# COUNT and GROUP BY on different tables

Tags: oracle, group-by, count

I have three tables:
T_BUSINESS_LOC (Contains business location)

```
Person_ID | Business_loc
---------------------
101         Delhi      
102         Mumbai     
103         Noida      
104         Mumbai     
105         Noida      
106         Delhi      
107         Mumbai     
108         Delhi      
109         Mumbai
```

T_LOG_ACCESS (Contains session details as date and time)

```
Person_ID | ACCESS_DATE
---------------------
101         23-OCT-17 12.07.55.027206000 AM
101         25-OCT-17 12.10.36.522369000 AM
102         23-OCT-17 12.52.52.289198000 AM
103         23-OCT-17 12.15.58.494122000 AM
103         23-OCT-17 12.15.58.494122000 AM
103         24-OCT-17 12.23.41.205421000 AM
104         23-OCT-17 12.05.05.726392000 AM
104         25-OCT-17 12.05.05.726392000 AM
108         23-OCT-17 06.48.36.399221000 AM
109         23-OCT-17 06.53.13.026891000 AM
109         25-OCT-17 12.05.05.726392000 AM
```

PERSON_ROLE (Contains user role)

```
Person_ID | assigned_role
---------------------
101         HR_Role
102         MN_Role
103         HR_Role
104         HR_Role
105         MN_Role
106         Cont_Role      
107         HR_Role     
108         Cont_Role
109         MN_Role
```

I am trying to get the count of the users who accessed on 23rd October only; group by location such that the output comes as following:

```
Location  |  MN_Role_Count   |   HR_Role_Count   |   Cont_Role_Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Delhi       1                   1                    1
Mumbai      1                   0                    0
Noida       0                   2                    0
```

I am trying to achieve this with the following query but with no success:

```
select a.location,
count (a.Person_id) AS MN_Role_Count, count (b.oprid) AS HR_Role_Count,  
count (c.oprid) AS Cont_Role_Count from T_BUSINESS_LOC  a, T_BUSINESS_LOC  
b, T_BUSINESS_LOC c where a.Person_id in (select distinct (ac1.Person_id) 
from T_LOG_ACCESS ac1 where ac1.T_LOG_ACCESS like '23-OCT-17%' and 
ac1.Person_id in (select ps1.assigned_role from PERSON_ROLE ps1 where 
ps1.assigned_role='MN_Role'))
and b.oprid in (select distinct (ac2.Person_id) from T_LOG_ACCESS ac2 where 
ac2.T_LOG_ACCESS like '23-OCT-17%' and ac2.Person_id in (select 
ps2.assigned_role from PERSON_ROLE ps2 where ps2.rolename='HR_Role'))
and c.oprid in (select distinct (ac3.Person_id) from T_LOG_ACCESS ac3 where 
ac3.T_LOG_ACCESS like '23-OCT-17%' and ac3.Person_id in (select 
ps3.assigned_role from PERSON_ROLE ps3 where ps3.rolename='Cont_Role'))
group by a.location;
```

Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

### TRY THIS:

```
   with T_BUSINESS_LOC (Person_ID, Business_loc) as (
    select 101, 'Delhi'  from dual union all
    select 102, 'Mumbai' from dual union all
    select 103, 'Noida'  from dual union all
    select 104, 'Mumbai' from dual union all
    select 105, 'Noida'  from dual union all
    select 106, 'Delhi'  from dual union all
    select 107, 'Mumbai' from dual union all
    select 108, 'Delhi'  from dual union all
    select 109, 'Mumbai' from dual ),
  T_LOG_ACCESS(Person_ID, ACCESS_DATE) as (
    select 101, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:07:55.027206000' from dual union all
    select 101, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:10:36.522369000' from dual union all
    select 102, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:52:52.289198000' from dual union all
    select 103, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:15:58.494122000' from dual union all
    select 103, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:15:58.494122000' from dual union all
    select 103, timestamp '2017-10-24 12:23:41.205421000' from dual union all
    select 104, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:05:05.726392000' from dual union all
    select 104, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:05:05.726392000' from dual union all
    select 108, timestamp '2017-10-23 06:48:36.399221000' from dual union all
    select 109, timestamp '2017-10-23 06:53:13.026891000' from dual union all
    select 109, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:05:05.726392000' from dual ),
  PERSON_ROLE(Person_ID, assigned_role) as (
    select 101, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 102, 'MN_Role'   from dual union all
    select 103, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 104, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 105, 'MN_Role'   from dual union all
    select 106, 'Cont_Role' from dual union all
    select 107, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 108, 'Cont_Role' from dual union all
    select 109, 'MN_Role'   from dual )   
    select
    business_loc,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB2.assigned_role='MN_Role'   THEN SUB1.ACCESS_DATE END)MN_Role_Count ,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB2.assigned_role='HR_Role'   THEN SUB1.ACCESS_DATE END)HR_Role_Count ,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB2.assigned_role='Cont_Role' THEN SUB1.ACCESS_DATE END)Cont_Role_Count   
    from
    T_BUSINESS_LOC MAIN
    INNER JOIN T_LOG_ACCESS  SUB1 ON MAIN.PERSON_ID=SUB1.PERSON_ID and TRUNC(SUB1.ACCESS_DATE)=TO_DATE('20171023','YYYYMMDD')
    INNER JOIN PERSON_ROLE   SUB2 ON MAIN.PERSON_ID=SUB2.PERSON_ID
    group by business_loc
```

Comment: Hi Ersin, thanks for your help, but I am getting error on following line: INNER JOIN T_LOG_ACCESS  SUB1 ON MAIN.PERSON_ID=SUB1.PERSON_ID ON TRUNC(SUB1.ACCESS_DATE)=TO_DATE('20170123','YYYYMMDD')

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 59

Comment: Thanks, can this query provide distinct count for a duplicate ID (like 103 in my case)?

Comment: EDITED , PLS LOOK AGAIN

Comment: Thanks Ersin. I was wondering how to further tweak the query for a date range. Example, TRUNC(SUB1.ACCESS_DATE) between TO_DATE('20171001','YYYYMMDD')and TO_DATE('20171031','YYYYMMDD')

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Oracle 11 or higher You could use `pivot`:

```
with T_BUSINESS_LOC (Person_ID, Business_loc) as (
    select 101, 'Delhi'  from dual union all
    select 102, 'Mumbai' from dual union all
    select 103, 'Noida'  from dual union all
    select 104, 'Mumbai' from dual union all
    select 105, 'Noida'  from dual union all
    select 106, 'Delhi'  from dual union all
    select 107, 'Mumbai' from dual union all
    select 108, 'Delhi'  from dual union all
    select 109, 'Mumbai' from dual ),
  T_LOG_ACCESS(Person_ID, ACCESS_DATE) as (
    select 101, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:07:55.027206000' from dual union all
    select 101, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:10:36.522369000' from dual union all
    select 102, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:52:52.289198000' from dual union all
    select 103, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:15:58.494122000' from dual union all
    select 103, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:15:58.494122000' from dual union all
    select 103, timestamp '2017-10-24 12:23:41.205421000' from dual union all
    select 104, timestamp '2017-10-23 12:05:05.726392000' from dual union all
    select 104, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:05:05.726392000' from dual union all
    select 108, timestamp '2017-10-23 06:48:36.399221000' from dual union all
    select 109, timestamp '2017-10-23 06:53:13.026891000' from dual union all
    select 109, timestamp '2017-10-25 12:05:05.726392000' from dual ),
  PERSON_ROLE(Person_ID, assigned_role) as (
    select 101, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 102, 'MN_Role'   from dual union all
    select 103, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 104, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 105, 'MN_Role'   from dual union all
    select 106, 'Cont_Role' from dual union all
    select 107, 'HR_Role'   from dual union all
    select 108, 'Cont_Role' from dual union all
    select 109, 'MN_Role'   from dual )
-- end of data, query starts here
select * 
  from (
    select business_loc loc, assigned_role rol
      from t_log_access 
      join t_business_loc using (person_id)
      join person_role using (person_id)
      where date '2017-10-23' <= access_date and access_date < date '2017-10-24')
  pivot (count(1) for rol in ('MN_Role'   Mn_Role_Count, 
                              'HR_Role'   HR_Role_Count, 
                              'Cont_Role' Cont_Role_Count))
  order by loc
```

Result:

```
LOC    MN_ROLE_COUNT HR_ROLE_COUNT CONT_ROLE_COUNT
------ ------------- ------------- ---------------
Delhi              0             1               1
Mumbai             1             1               0
Noida              0             2               0
```

Comment: Hi Ponder, thanks for your help. Actually, the session data is in thousands and the same is for person ID.Besides, the locations too are 100+ in live data. For the sake of simplicity, I provided only a handful of data here.

Comment: I know, you need only last part of answer, starting from `select ...`